# Patch for module applies with patch command but not composer

Tags: composer

I have encountered a weird issue in which a patch I rolled for Commerce does not apply with Composer; it gives no errors, but the patch is not actually applied.

```
  "extra": {
    "patches": {
      "drupal/commerce" : {
        "Allow order types to have no cart": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/commerce-direct-checkout-2.2-2810723-37.patch"
      },
```

However, the same patch applies correctly after downloading and using the `patch` command:

```
/web/modules/contrib/commerce$ patch -p1 < ../../../../patches/commerce-direct-checkout-2.2-2810723-37.patch
patching file modules/cart/src/Form/AddToCartForm.php
patching file modules/cart/tests/src/Functional/AddToCartFormTest.php
patching file modules/cart/tests/src/Functional/CartBrowserTestBase.php
patching file modules/product/config/schema/commerce_product.schema.yml
patching file modules/product/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/AddToCartFormatter.php
patching file modules/product/src/ProductLazyBuilders.php
```

What is wrong with my patch that makes it fail in Composer?

Comment: That is a weird issue. I added your patch in my composer.json file and it was applied correctly. I noticed that you have a comma at the end of the drupal/commerce patch entry in your composer.json and am assuming you have other patches. Do they get applied correctly with composer?

Comment: @Patrick Kenny if below answer doesn't work for you try to remove /web from patch file when applying with composer since it tries to apply it based on Drupal/core repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is an [issue with Drupal patches for composer when using an older version of Git.](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/174)  The problem is with composer-patches 1.6.3.

Three possible solutions for now until the bug gets fixed.

**Force 1.6.2**

In `composer.json`, specify 1.6.2:

```
"require": {
"composer/installers": "^1.0.20",
"cweagans/composer-patches": "1.6.2",
```

**Force git clone with 1.6.3**

In `composer.json`, instead of "dist", use "source":

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "source"
  },
```

**Update git to the latest version**

Answer (score 1):

The above didn't work for me but I debugged this issue by running composer install -v for verbosity.

It will show you, for example that it is running the command

```
patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/core' < '/my/path/to/patch.patch'
```

I believe the -d indicates that we are running the patch from the web/core directory. When I look at this patch it looked like:

```
diff --git a/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js b/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
index 4548c013a..f930746b3 100644
--- a/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
+++ b/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
@@ -170,7 +170,10 @@
   // code here
```

The a/b indicates the location of the files to patch. Since we are already in the web/core folder, it cannot find the web/core directory inside there and so fails. If we edit those two lines without that in there, it worked. ie

```
diff --git a/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js b/web/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
index 4548c013a..f930746b3 100644
--- a/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
+++ b/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.js
@@ -170,7 +170,10 @@
// code here
```